# How many tapes would Turing Machine require to find the sum of 2 integers (expressed in base2)?

Tags: turing-machines

Suppose I wished to devise an algorithm (to be run on a turing machine) which could find the sum of 2 integers (expressed in base2). How many tapes would this require?

My intuition tells me that 4 tapes would be required: 1 for each of the two numbers being added together, 1 to store the 'carry over' value, and 1 to store the output.

Is this correct? Could it be done with fewer tapes?

Comment: It can be done with 1 tape. The tapes are infinite, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that can be computed with any reasonable extension of a Turing machine can be computed with the standard Turing machine that has a single one-way infinite tape.

For example, you can simulate a four-tape machine by interleaving the characters of the tapes so that, e.g., the four tapes

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
    a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots\\
    b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & \cdots\\
    c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & \cdots\\
    d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & \cdots
\end{array}$$

with the single tape
$$a_1\ b_1\ c_1\ d_1\ a_2\ b_2\ c_2\ d_2\ a_3\ b_3\ c_3\ d_3\ \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would this machine work though? Would the $c_i$ terms not just be represented by different  states of the head?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The values $c_1, c_2, \dots$ are the characters stored on the third tape. Actually, the situation is slightly more complicated than I stated, since you also need to keep track of where the tape heads are.